# Sending gps data from Flutter app to arduino via Bluetooth

Tags: flutter, arduino, bluetooth

Is there anyway to send data from my flutter app to arduino. I have read through the documentation of flutter blue and flutter bluetooth serial and I can't seem to find any information relating to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course possible. You need a client-server or master-slave implementation. I am assuming that you want to use Bluetooth LE. You have to make sure that a script is running on the Arduino which receives the Bluetooth data and reacts accordingly. Take a look at the following tutorial: [How to communicate through BLE using Flutter](https://blog.kuzzle.io/communicate-through-ble-using-flutter) and look at the Bluetooth LE protocol. I recommend the BLE Scanner App from Google Play to test a BLE connection. Then you can see a lot information like BLE Services, Characteristics and stuff like that you need to work with BLE.